# How to bring Print Dialog box to front?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have a Print Button to print my Crystal report directly to the printer. My code is as below:

```
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportClass clsReport = new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportClass();

protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog dialog1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog();



    dialog1.AllowSomePages = true;
    dialog1.AllowPrintToFile = false;


    if (dialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        int copies = dialog1.PrinterSettings.Copies;
        int fromPage = dialog1.PrinterSettings.FromPage;
        int toPage = dialog1.PrinterSettings.ToPage;
        bool collate = dialog1.PrinterSettings.Collate;

        clsReport.PrintOptions.PrinterName = dialog1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
        clsReport.PrintToPrinter(copies, collate, fromPage, toPage);



    }

}
```

This working fine but my problem is, whenever I click on Print Button the Print Dialoq appears at the back of all pages so that sometimes I cannot see even that it came or not. So, I want to bring the Print Dialog box in front so on top of all window.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't use `WinForm` components in ASP.NET -- they wont work on remote client.

Comment: then what can I use..can you suggest please?

Comment: Of course, Use crystal reporting ASP.NET controls -- you can add them declaravitely or create dynamically.